# How to fix a MacBook's sound output which is stuck on headphones?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, hardware, system-settings

I have a late 2008 My MacBook running OS X Yosemite. It suddenly stopped playing audio through the internal speakers. I've checked **Sound** under System Preferences, and headphones show up as the selected device for sound output. I tried connecting and disconnecting some headphones, and the MacBook did change the output to internal speakers, but only for a second. I then tried restarting the MacBook to see if it was something with software but it stayed the same. I also tried lightly cleaning the headphone port with a q-tip but that did not work.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Have you tried a different user account? If it's a software setting issue, it's likely that the other users account will work OK. If the other user account is the same then it proves its a hardware issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting some compressed air at Wal-Mart or Best Buy or another retailer and blow the headphone jack clean with that. A can will cost about $5 and you'll need to be 18 or older to buy it.

If it still doesn't work after that, the headphone jack will likely need to be replaced. Unless you do electronics repair, find a professional to replace it for you.